# How to use switch statement and array in java?

Tags: java

I am practicing switch statement in java, and I have came across this example in java where I am trying to write a program which will have name of an artist and list of 17 songs of that artist. In one case I have to print out the 16th element of the array and another case I have to print out the last element of the array and by default it will print out everything (artist name and 17 songs). 
So, far I have declared the array:

```
 public class q7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //String[] artist = {"Tahsan"};

        //declaring an array that contains 18 elements in total, which includes the name of the artist and 17 tracks
        String[] songs = {"Tahsan", "Alo","Irsha", "Odrissho Robi","Prematal", "Aalo", "Nei", "Rodela Dupur","Ke Tumi",
                "Alo","Brittalpona","durotto","Brishtite","Durey","Bhalobashar Maane","Tomay Ghire","Kothopokhoton", "Prottaborton"
                };


        for (String i : songs){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        switch(){

        }
    }
```

How should I start writing the switch statement?

Comment: you have todo something like this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-statement-in-java/

Comment: @RamPrakash yes something like this but instead of single statement, I have to print out the entire array, and one SPECIFIC element from a specific index of the array.

Comment: have alook at https://www.developer.com/java/data/seven-ways-to-refactor-java-switch-statements.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it was not given on what parameter switch case needs to work I have taken input from the user and added the following case asked.
For more information regarding switch case, you can refer to [switch case in Java GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-statement-in-java/)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class q7 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //String[] artist = {"Tahsan"};

    //declaring an array that contains 18 elements in total, which includes the name of the artist and 17 tracks
    String[] songs = {"Tahsan", "Alo","Irsha", "Odrissho Robi","Prematal", "Aalo", "Nei", "Rodela Dupur","Ke Tumi",
            "Alo","Brittalpona","durotto","Brishtite","Durey","Bhalobashar Maane","Tomay Ghire","Kothopokhoton", "Prottaborton"
            };
    int testCase = keyboard.nextInt();
    switch(testCase){
        case 1: System.out.println(songs[16]);
               break;
        case 2: System.out.println(songs[songs.length-1]);
               break;
        default :   for (String i : songs)
                        System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement is fairly similar to an if statement, where each 'case' is a condition for some object/value.

Therefor, if you had an index for your array that was inputted by something else (e.g. a user selected it), it would look like this:

```
switch(songs[index]){
    case "Tahsan": System.out.println(songs[index]);
        break;
    case "Alo": System.out.println(songs[index]);
        break;
    //etc etc
    default: 
        for (String i : songs){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
}
```

you could also use the index itself as the conditional value.

```
switch(index){
    case 1: System.out.println(songs[1]);
        break;
    case 2: System.out.println(songs[2]);
        break;
    default: 
        for (String i : songs){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
}
```

etc.

It doesn't make much practical sense if you don't have the index being chosen by some other system (some other application or a user for example), but that is the gist of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should define switch case statements.

```
        //declaring an array that contains 18 elements in total, which includes the name of the artist and 17 tracks
    String[] songs = {"Tahsan", "Alo","Irsha", "Odrissho Robi","Prematal", "Aalo", "Nei", "Rodela Dupur","Ke Tumi",
            "Alo","Brittalpona","durotto","Brishtite","Durey","Bhalobashar Maane","Tomay Ghire","Kothopokhoton", "Prottaborton"
            };


    for (String i : songs){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    int type=0;
    switch(type){
      case 0:
       System.out.println(songs[16]);
      break;
      case 1:
       System.out.println(songs[songs.length()-1]);
      break;
      default:
        for (String i : songs){
        System.out.println(i);
         }

    }
```

You should change type value. It is better if you take it from user.